# About Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How can I prove this fact:

We're working in a Hilbert space $$ \mathcal{H} := \left\{ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in {\mathbb{R}}^{\mathbb{N}} \mid \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\,(x_n)^2 < \infty \right\} $$ and we're taking this metric, which we can proof is an ultrametric $$ d(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = \dfrac{1}{2^k} $$ where $k$ is the first different component in both successions. What I'm trying to proof is:

Let be $\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{H}$, with $\mathcal{H}$ Hilbert space and $\varepsilon > 0$. Show that if $\mathbf{y} \in B_{\varepsilon}\,(\mathbf{x})$, then $B_{\varepsilon}\,(\mathbf{x}) = B_{\varepsilon}\,(\mathbf{y})$.

Thank you so much

Comment: Just to be clear, what does $B_\varepsilon(\bf x)$ mean?

Comment: $B_{\varepsilon}(\mathbf{x}$) means the ball with center in $\mathbf{x}$ and radius $\varepsilon$

Comment: This is not true. You can find a counterexample in the simplest possible Hilbert space: $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm working in thsi metric space: $\mathcal{H} := \left\{ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in {\mathbb{R}}^{\mathbb{N}} \mid \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\,(x_n)^2 < \infty \right\}$

Comment: It is true in ultrametric spaces ($d(x,z) \le \max(d(x,y), d(y,z))$, but Hilbert spaces aren't that..

Comment: We've got this metric for this space: $d(x_n,y_n) = \dfrac{1}{2^k}$, where $k$ is the first component different in both successions, and we can show this is an ultrametric

Comment: If you're working with a specific space, you should put that Hilbert space definition in the original question.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that a Hilbert space is a vector space with an inner product, which in turns make it a normed space, which in turn makes it into a metric space. Once you change the metric (and you have), then you just have a metric space, not a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 2):

I can't post comments, but i guess you got a typo there. If not, this is obviously wrong. Consider any ball in $\Bbb R^2$ with the standard scalar product, and think about it geometrically.

(Please feel free to delete the answer again after an update from the OP)

Comment: That's the weird think. What I'm trying to proof is that in any Hilbert space, if two balls are not disjoint, they're the same ball, it's really weird

Comment: @user115595 It's not true.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general fact for any ultrametric space $(X,d)$: this is a metric space where the triangle inequality is strengthened to: for all $x,y,z \in X$ we have $d(x,z) \le \max(d(x,y), d(y,z))$. In that case, any two $r$-balls either are disjoint, or are equal.

For suppose that $z \in B_r(x) \cap B_r(y)$. So $d(x,z) < r$ and $d(y,z) < r$. It follows that $d(x,y) \le \max(d(x,z),d(z,y)) < r$ as well (the maximum of two numbers less than $r$ is also less than $r$).

Now suppose $u \in B_r(x)$, we want to show it is in $B_r(y)$, to get one inclusion. So we know that $d(u,x) < r$ and so $d(u,y) \le \max(d(u,x), d(x,y)) < r$, as both numbers are $<r$ again. Symmetrically, if $u \in B_r(y)$, then $u \in B_r(x)$, so we have equality of the sets $B_r(x)$ and $B_r(y)$.